# Are image processing questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, topicality

I noticed two questions, [this one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/626/computational-complexity-of-image-segmentation-algorithms) and [this one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/618/multi-objective-optimization-problem-euclidean-space), that seem to be about image processing, or possibly just research CS regarding images.

Are these on- or off-topic?

If off-topic, should these be moved to theoretical CS?

Comment: the 'computational complexity' question is not of the sort of computational complexity that would be encouraged at cstheory.SE (it also does not seem research level), the second question is probably too applied for cstheory. Both question have a problem of being unclear and under-specified.

Comment: Maybe Stack overflow, then? I agree with you that both questions are unclear and underspecified, so it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), despite its [name](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1), welcomes image processing questions. If it is ever deemed that those questions have to be migrated somewhere, that is the site to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question about computational complexity isn't a good fit for the site, if only because computational complexity of algorithms tends to be more of a theoretical CS question (exceptions for SciComp would probably be along the lines of graph-theoretic algorithms or numerical linear algebra).

The question about optimization algorithms *could* be on-topic, but that poster's question leaves much to be desired. It's not clear what type of problem he is trying to set up.

I could see image processing questions being on topic if they involve numerical algorithms. Otherwise, I think they're probably a better fit elsewhere.

Comment: Nothing wrong with computational complexity questions related to any numerical algorithm.  For instance, you could discuss the computational complexity of high-order versus low-order FEM.

Comment: Agreed. Numerical algorithms are on topic, data structures might be on topic, the computational complexity of something unrelated to numerics or graph theory is not.